# Event handling in EmberJS components using {{#event}} blocks

Tags: ember.js

I've been working on a UI in Ember and I am having difficulty implementing some of the event handling as described on the documentation [here](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/handling-events/)

I have a section of a nav bar I need to highlight on hover. The nav bar is made up of [ember-bootstrap components](https://www.ember-bootstrap.com/).

```
    {{#bs-navbar type="dark" backgroundColor="primary" as |navbar|}}
{{navbar.toggle}}
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding-left:50px;padding-right:50px; ">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img style="max-width:250px; margin-top: -12px;margin-bottom: -12px" src="/assets/images/logo_white_3x.png"></a>
    {{#navbar.content}}
        {{#navbar.nav as |nav|}}
            {{#nav.item class="highlight-active"}}
                {{#nav.link-to "index"}}LIVE{{/nav.link-to}}
            {{/nav.item}}
        {{/navbar.nav}}
    {{/navbar.content}}
    <div class="navbar-nav mr-left">
        {{#navbar.content}}
            {{#navbar.nav as |nav|}}
                {{#nav.dropdown class="{{isHover}}" as |dd|}}
                    {{#dd.toggle }}Link<span class="caret"></span>{{/dd.toggle}}
                        {{#dd.menu as |ddm|}}
                            {{#ddm.item}}{{#ddm.link-to "index"}}Link{{/ddm.link-to}}{{/ddm.item}}
                            {{#ddm.item}}{{#ddm.link-to "cau.all"}}Link{{/ddm.link-to}}{{/ddm.item}}
                        {{/dd.menu}}
                {{/nav.dropdown}}
                {{#nav.item}}
                    {{#nav.link-to "index"}}Current User: <b>MICKEY MOUSE</b>{{/nav.link-to}}
                {{/nav.item}}
            {{/navbar.nav}}
        {{/navbar.content}}
    </div>
</div>
{{/bs-navbar}}
```

To accomplish this I tried to use one of the block events described n the documentation:

```
 //template
 {{#hover}}
  <h1>link</h1>
 {{/hover}}

//component
export default Component.extend({
  hover() {
    alert('hovered')
  },
  actions: {
      //actions here
  }
});
```

This produces the following error: `hover not found, and the catch-all block handler didn't handle it`

I thought it might be because the name of the even must be hyphenated so changed it accordingly. This produced a `no component or helper by that name` error.

Copying and pasting the same text from the guide produces the same errors which suggests there is something more fundamental I am not understanding.

Can anyone shed any light?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, if you need to highlight a navbar on hover, you should be doing this with css.

```
.someClass:hover: {
  //apply highlight style
}
```

As for what's wrong with what you're doing in general, go back and look at those linked docs again. There's no event that ember handles called `hover`. What you're looking for is `mouseEnter` and `mouseLeave`. Check this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/ae983731fbd81efc70bf52a9bb1aafb5?openFiles=templates.components.hover-block.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.hover-block.hbs) to see an example:

```
export default Component.extend({
  mouseEnter(){
    this.set('hovering', true); 
  },
  mouseLeave(){
    this.set('hovering', false);
  }
});
```

Where we only show the passed block on hover

```
Hover here -> 
{{#if hovering}}
{{yield}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Yes the main mistake I was making was not realising that the {{#double-clickable}} was a yielding component. I thought it was a different kind of helper to register an 'event' area. Thanks for the clarification. Does this mean if you wanted to affect a parent component through an event in this way you'd need to use a closure action?

Answer (score 2):

Try use an action for the [`mouseEnter`](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/handling-events/#toc_event-names) event, e.g. `<div mouseEnter={{action "showCaution"}}>`

> Another way to preserve native event behaviors and use an action, is
>   to assign a (closure) action to an inline event handler.

The action is simply a function defined on the actions hash of a component. Since the action is assigned to an inline handler, the function definition can define the event object as its first parameter.

```
actions: {
  showCaution(event){
    // Only when assigning the action to an inline handler, the event object
    // is passed to the action as the first parameter.
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've used this method in other parts of the application but I wasn't able to use it with the example above with the ember-bootstrap add on. I couldn't add the action helper to the existing {{dd.dropdown}} without being able to extend the ember-bootstrap components (i think).